# Rename localhost 127.0.0.1, in LAMP stack

Tags: linux, apache

I am using a LAMP stack. Will there be problems if I update the /etc/host file to reflect `127.0.0.1` as `somename` from `localhost`?

Thanks!

Edit:
I sometimes work in remote sites with no network. I have the same setup on different machines and I need the server name to know dynamically where to do changes, etc.

I edited `/etc/hosts` to show
`127.0.0.1 localhost somename`

Now, with my Wifi off I am trying `http://somename` and it is not connecting. If I turn my wifi on, it works. But I need it to work with no connection. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

No. Just add `somename` after `localhost` separated by space in `/etc/hosts`. You can add as many aliases as you like, as long as you don't delete `localhost`.